# w_scan: no data from PAT

Tags: usb, video, dvb

I'm using w_scan to get channel list for my DVB-T stick. But despite channels being found, channels.conf file is empty. I suspect `Info: no data from PAT` has something to do with this.

I know the DVB-T stick is working, because if I enter the frequency into VLC player, I can watch the first channel (SLO1).

Terminal output:

```
[rok@rok-laptop ~]$ w_scan -c SI > channels.conf
w_scan version 20120605 (compiled for DVB API 5.6)
using settings for SLOVENIA

842000: (time: 03:54) 
850000: (time: 03:59) 
858000: (time: 04:03) 
tune to: QAM_64   f = 562000 kHz I999B8C23D0T8G4Y0 
(time: 04:06) Info: no data from PAT
    service = SLO1 (RTV SLOVENIJA)
    service = SLO2 (RTV SLOVENIJA)
    service = SLO3 (RTV SLOVENIJA)
    service = POP TV (PROPLUS)
    service = KANAL A (PROPLUS)
    service = GOLICA TV (GOLICA TV)
    service = VAS KANAL (TV NOVO MESTO)
    service = TV PINK 3 (AGENCIJA MEDIAS)
    service = TV NAKUPI (DOMATES)
dumping lists (0 services)
Done.
```